# Can I define an array or a list from anonymous class?

Tags: c#, collections, anonymous-class

Can I define an array or a list from anonymous class?

like this:

```
persons = new ... [] 
{
 new { ID = 1, Name = "Name1"},
 new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you'll just need to type the `persons` variable implicitly and remove the type specifier from the array creation statement.

```
var persons = new []
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "Name1" },
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and Can I define a list directly (without pass an array to the list) ?

Comment: @Homam: Not directly (using list initializer syntax), as you'd have to specify the name of the anonymous type. You can, however, just call `ToList()` at the end of your array declaration and `persons` will then be a `List<>`.